# c# Get File Last Access or Usuability

Tags: c#, file, system.io.fileinfo, lastaccesstime

I need to inspect all files within a Repository periodically and compare its LastAccessTime in order to know when was the last time that file was used (accessed, modified and/or updated).

I've already been tried with File.GetLastAccessTime() and FileInfo.LastAccessTime, but I always get the same DateTime after open/close it, or read it.

How could I know when a file has been used?

Thanks!

```
string path = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/testing/doc2.txt"
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
Console.WriteLine("GetLastAccessTime {0}", File.GetLastAccessTime(path));
Console.WriteLine("GetLastAccessTimeUtc {0}", File.GetLastAccessTimeUtc(path));
Console.WriteLine("Directory.GetLastAccessTime {0}", Directory.GetLastAccessTime(path));
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path);
Console.WriteLine("fi.LastAccessTime {0}", fi.LastAccessTime);
```

### output:

```
GetLastAccessTime           12/18/2018 11:41:15 AM
GetLastAccessTimeUtc        12/18/2018 4:41:15 PM
Directory.GetLastAccessTime 12/18/2018 11:41:15 AM
fi.LastAccessTime           12/18/2018 11:41:15 AM
--------------------------------------
GetLastAccessTime           12/18/2018 11:41:15 AM
GetLastAccessTimeUtc        12/18/2018 4:41:15 PM
Directory.GetLastAccessTime 12/18/2018 11:41:15 AM
fi.LastAccessTime           12/18/2018 11:41:15 AM
```

Comment: Are you saying the `File.GetLastAccessTime()` isn't reflecting when a file has been opened or read?

Comment: Read through the Remarks section of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getlastaccesstime?view=netframework-4.7.2) and make sure that your case doesn't fall into one of those conditions.

Comment: From the documentation that @SamW mentions: _This method may return an inaccurate value, because it uses native functions whose values may not be continuously updated by the operating system._

Comment: Can you add your code? Are you certain the file path is correct? As per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2973642/3723088) you will still get a default `DateTime` value back if the files does not exist. What `DateTime` are you getting?

Comment: @SamW you got it above

Comment: @Leonardo What DateTime are you expecting if 11:41:15 AM is not correct? Is your file system FAT, NTFS or something else?

Comment: @SamW DateTime format is correct but always get the same value even though after open or read the file.

Comment: @Leonardo it seems you are right. I tested it on NTFS and FAT16 *(flash drive)*. Result: NTFS: time did not change even after the file was rewritten. last access time = creation time; test file was the test application. FAT16: last access time is correct day at 0:00:00 (midnight) in GMT+1 *(my time zone - CET)*, this means 23:00:00 previous day in UTC, and 1:00:00 for time saving period (summer time date). Tested in Windows 7.

Comment: I know the format is correct but what _time_ do you expect it to return? Again, what is your file system?

Comment: @SamW NTFS and what I expect is that after open/read the file I get a different DateTime (a little more recent, of course). So, my idea is to compare day-by-day the DateTime of that file and, if it happens to be different, that would mean that the file was used (open or read or whatever)

Answer (score 2):

The most important thing is, what file system you are using. I suppose it is NTFS. Then there a few quotations:

> Last access timestamp of a file is the last date and time when that file was opened for reading or writing. So every time a user access a file this timestamp needs to be updated, which is a bit of an overhead especially if you are not too keen on this file attribute. **To improve the performance of NTFS filesystem in Windows 10 (and previous versions starting from Windows Vista) the last access times of files and directories are NOT updated.**

Source [here](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/windows-10/129/enable-last-access-time.html)

> Bonus chatter: Starting in Windows Vista, maintaining the last-access time is disabled by default. In practice, this means that the number of bugs related to altering the last-access time accidentally will multiply unchecked, because the mechanism for detecting the error is disabled by default.

Source [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111010-00/?p=9433/)

And [one more link](http://port139.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/12/12/190632), where it seems like there is still another behaviour.

And [last link for FAT](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-NewFileTime&faq=2). I'm not so sure, since I last read only the FAT12 *(floppy drive/diskettes)* description many, many rears ago, but there probably is not a space to store last access time in FAT file systems, only the date is stored. I can not confirm this for the extension Microsoft provided with long file names.